# How to combine variables to represent scientific notation in C?

Tags: c, scientific-notation

If I have

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
```

How can I make it so that

double result = 3e5, but only using variables?

I know aeb won't work, obviously.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: Like `double result = a * exp10((double)b);`?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it makes sense to me

Comment: You could write a function to append 0's based on the a/b params

Comment: I mean instead of the normal 3e5, I have the numbers 3 and 5 stored in variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function `atof` defined in `stdlib.h` and `sprintf`:

```
float a = 3;
int b = 5;

char tmp[10];
sprintf(tmp, "%fe%d", a, b);

double x = atof(tmp);
printf("x = %fe%d = %f\n", a, b, x);
```

Output: http://ideone.com/NdDcNB

```
x = 3.000000e5 = 300000.000000
```

Comment: You may want to use `snprintf` and a larger buffer size in case `a` and `b` become very big.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
double result = a * pow(10.0,(double)b);
```

Or, with GNU extensions:

```
double result = a * exp10((double)b);
```

In either case, #include math.h and link with the math library (eg. `-lm`).  This is likely much more efficient than piecing together a string and converting to double.

Comment: This is more efficient but is less accurate in a good C implementation. The result of `pow` may have some error, and the multiplication may have some error. In a good C implementation, `atof` produces the most accurate result possible. However, the C standard does not require this.